# How to convert integer type to amount type in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I format numbers as money in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149055/how-can-i-format-numbers-as-money-in-javascript)

In JavaScript I accessed a variable like this:

```
amount= document.getElementById('<%= DataItemValue1.ClientID%>').firstChild.nodeValue;
```

Now if the amount is `10945` I want it as `$10,945`; if `1098` as `$1,098`

How can I do this in javascript and pass it to a label?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: thankyou frederic it really worked without even changing a single line.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

```
function amount( value ) {
    value = value.toString();
    var o = '';
    do {
        var s = value.substr( -3 );
        value = value.substr( 0, value.length - 3 );
        o = (value.length?',':'')+s+o;
    } while( value.length );
    return '$'+o;
}
```